# Postgres seach jsonb with indexes

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, jsonb, trigram

Im new to postgres jsonb operation.
Im storing some data in Postgres with jsonb column, which has flexible metadata as below.
I wanted to search different unique metadata (key:value pairs)

```
id, type, metadata
1, player, {"name": "john", "height": 180, "team": "xyz"}
2, game,   {"name": "afl", "members": 10, "team": "xyz"}
```

results should be something like below, distinct, order by asc. I wanted it to be efficient using some indexes.

```
key    | value
______________
height   180
members  10
name     alf
name     john
team     xyz
```

My solution below hit the index for search but sorting and distinct wont hit any indexes as they are processed values from jsonb.

```
CREATE INDEX metadata_jsonb_each_text_idx ON table
USING GIN (jsonb_pretty(metadata) gin_trgm_ops);

select distinct t, t.* 
from table u, jsonb_each_text(u.metadata) t 
where jsonb_pretty(u.metadata) like '%key%' 
order by t.key, t.value
```

Appreciate any thoughts on this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `%key%` is so short and common that it matches so many rows that an index scan is inefficient? To test if the index could be used (and would perform better), `SET enable_seqscan = off;`.

Comment: yeah until I set seq scan off, I didnt see this index working as well. but my concern is how can I create a index to support sorting/distinct, which slows down my query a lot. abt 10times slower with 100k+ data set

Comment: You can use the `?` operator with a plain GIN index to search the JSON for certain keys. But I don't think that a substring search like you are planning can be made efficient.

Comment: hmmm I wanted to search everything in metadata with search key, including json keys and values. thats why I used `jsonb_pretty()` .
however I think search is quite efficient without sort/distinct this query run in 20ms.  
sort/distinct is the culprit here, no idea how to improve it